# Ошибка при проверке условия response.isSuccessful()

Tags: android

Добрый день. При запуске кода в снекбаре выводится Fail. С чем это может быть связано и как это пофиксить?

```
call.enqueue(new Callback<ContactList>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<ContactList> call, Response<ContactList> response) {
                            //Dismiss Dialog
                            dialog.dismiss();

                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                contactList = response.body().getContacts();
                                adapter = new ContactAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
                                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                            } else {
                                Snackbar.make(parentView, "Fail", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Ошибка может иметь 42+ причины. Смотрите что отвечает сервер. Например выведите его ответ в логи и поместите в вопрос. Что-то типа `response.errorBoby().string()`

Comment: Ещё посоветую OkHttp Logging Interceptor с уровнем логирования `Body`